# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 3 and input n_features is 2

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am continuously trying to fix it but won't be able to understand the fact. How can I fix it?

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 3 and input n_features is 2
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals import joblib

# music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
# X = music_data.drop(columns = ['genre'])
# y = music_data['genre']
# concat_music_data = pd.concat([y])

# model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# model.fit(X, y)

model = joblib.load('music-recommender.joblib')
predictions = model.predict([[21, 1]])
predictions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re only passing in 2 features to your predict method. This model expects 3 features.